# image html using XSL

Tags: html, xslt

I'm trying to display a image in HTML using XSL. I'm not very good with XSL so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

code:

```
<p class="span2">           
        <img src="{'images/aha/logo/' + {asn_code} + '.gif'}"/>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest Attribute Value Templates in this way. Additionally, `+` is not valid for concatenating strings. You should use `concat`.

So, you can do this....

```
<img src="{concat('images/aha/logo/', asn_code, '.gif')}"/>
```

But you could also do this (as multiple AVTs are allowed if they are not nested).

```
<img src="{'images/aha/logo/'}{asn_code}{'.gif'}"/>
```

But best of all, do this...

```
<img src="images/aha/logo/{asn_code}.gif"/>
```